# Securing FreeBSD in single user mode

Tags: freebsd

I have been shown that a FreeBSD system can easily be accessed in single user mode without the root password. Using the passwd command will allow anyone withh physical access to the system to change the password for root. Is there any way to prevent this? Before learning this I was told bsd systems are secure but now i am not so sure.

Comment: really funny, i'm going favorite this question, so i can have some laughs later on!

Comment: I dont see whats funny

Comment: He likely thinks it's "funny" because anyone with physical access to an unencrypted machine can boot whatever they want and access the raw data of the machine without restrictions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply need to edit `/etc/ttys` to prompt for a password in single user mode, although keep in mind anyone with physical access to the machine can still retrieve your data through various methods.

you will find a line that looks like this which is tab delimited in `/etc/ttys`:

```
console none   unknown off secure
```

change the **secure** part to **insecure** (very confusing, I know) so the line looks like this:

```
console none   unknown off insecure
```

upon rebooting and entering single user mode, you will be prompted for a password to get to the shell prompt.

This is what the FreeBSD guys have to say about using the word *insecure* in `/etc/ttys`:

> **Note:** An insecure console means that
>   you consider your physical security to
>   the console to be insecure, and want
>   to make sure only someone who knows
>   the root password may use single-user
>   mode, and it does not mean that you
>   want to run your console insecurely.
>   Thus, if you want security, choose
>   insecure, not secure.

Answer (score 5):

Any system that's physically accessable has the potential to be insecure. Even if your installed OS is secure, someone could, in theory use a live disk to edit security settings, reset passwords, or simply get data out.

I suppose you have to disable USB and cd boot and lock the bios to be totally safe. And even then someone could always take th HDD out.

I hope i don't make you too paranoid ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'password=SuperPasswordHere' >> /boot/loader.conf.local
```

It will force to ask for a password before jumping to single user mode

**P.S.** Pay attention on FreeBSD-9 if you using this. 
Someone broke a little bit this, but bug report and fixing solution already reported to GNAT.
See it here, 
[PR:170110](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=170110&cat=)

how to bring this functionality back on FreeBSD-9 that works for decades.

Without this fix computer will stop booting and will wait for a password

Answer (score 1):

Increase physical security.

Comment: see comment above please

Comment: The one you wrote after I answered? Oh, OK. Cool.